# anaconda cythonize C++ on windows 10

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio, cython

I have c++ code that compiles fine in MSVS 2015 which is installed on my PC.  I've been tasked to make a python extension using cython to be able to call c++ function from our python application.  I have installed anaconda 5.2 w/ cython installed already.  The c++ has a bunch of header files that need to be included when compiling.  I'm trying to build one function and am running into the same error.

My test.pyx looks like this for the one function:

```
cimport test
cimport cython
def pxd_PIXCIclose():
    res = test.pxd_PIXCIclose()
    return res
```

The test.pxd is as follows:

```
cdef extern from "D:\epix\inc\xcliball.h":  
int pxd_PIXCIclose()
```

setup.py is:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = Extension(
                name = "test",
                sources=["test.pyx"],
                include_dirs=["D:\epix\lib", "D:\epix\inc"],  
                library_dirs="D:\epix\inc\XCLIBW64.lib","D:\epix\lib\PXIPLW64.lib"]
              )

setup(
  name = "test.pyx",
  ext_modules = cythonize([ext_modules])
)
```

The test.c is created but then I get a bunch of build errors on the headers in the C++ include folder:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc

Compiling test.pyx because it depends on .\test.pxd.
[1/1] Cythonizing test.pyx
running build_ext
building 'test' extension

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe 
/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\epix\lib -ID:\epix\inc - 
IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" /Tctest.c 
/Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\test.obj
test.c

d:\epix\inc\pxlibsv.h(312): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'HANDLE'
d:\epix\inc\pxlibsv.h(317): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
d:\epix\inc\pxlibsv.h(827): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 
'*'
d:\epix\inc\pxlibsv.h(827): error C2081: 'HANDLE': name in formal parameter 
list illegal
d:\epix\inc\pxlibsv.h(827): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 
'*'
d:\epix\inc\pxlibsv.h(827): error C2059: syntax error: '*'
.
.
.
d:\epix\inc\xclibsc.h(369): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; 
stopping compilation
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I'm guessing my setup.py is not correct? Anyone have any pointers on what is happening?

Update to my original post, by adding #include windows.h, the original 'HANDLE' error is now gone but I received this link error now:

```
(base) d:\epix\cython>python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc
running build_ext
building 'test' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe 
/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Anaconda3\include -ID:\epix\lib - 
ID:\epix\inc -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program 
Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" /Tctest.c 
/Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\test.obj
test.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL 
/MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\Lib 
/LIBPATH:D:\epix\inc\XCLIBW64.lib /LIBPATH:D:\epix\lib\PXIPLW64.lib 
/LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_test build\temp.win-amd64- 
3.6\Release\test.obj /OUT:d:\epix\cython\test.cp36-win_amd64.pyd 
/IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\test.cp36-win_amd64.lib
test.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_test' specified multiple times; 
using first specification
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\test.cp36-win_amd64.lib 
and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\test.cp36-win_amd64.exp
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pxd_PIXCIclose
d:\epix\cython\test.cp36-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved 
externals error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Any suggestions on resolving this error?  Thank you.

Comment: The existence of `HANDLE` makes me think something your'e including is using the Windows headers. And it may be doing so only indirectly though a `stdafx.h`-style precompiled header setup. In which case I think you need to explicitly include that stdafx.h in your headers.

Comment: would I add that to the setup.py include_dirs or actually add #include <stdafx.h> to the headers?

Comment: I think you may have to add it to your headers, but I'm not actually sure, and I don't have a Windows box to test on, unfortunately.

Comment: This probably isn't your whole problem but: `test.pxd` is automatically cimported by `test.pyx` directly `test.pxd`s namespace. Therefore you may be ending up with multiple functions called `pxd_PIXCIclose()` (at least from Cython's point of view). Either rename the Cython function, or the pxd file.

Comment: HI DavidW - I changed the pxd name but still receive the same errors.  Thx for catching that.

Comment: Hi abarnert - I've yet to figure how to #include <stdafx.h> into the cython project, I took the first file in the error msg, pxlibsv.h, and included stdafx.h but it says it can't find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on compiler output, HANDLE is not defined. Did you know, that with VS2015 you need to add path to SDK ? It is not included, as I can see. Add  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10 \ include\ platformtoolset\um to path.  Platformtoolset will define subfolder in yours include path. Hope it helps.

Comment: @sllwine please see above

Comment: Hi Valeca, my system variable does have 'path' set to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\', as you can see in my original post, folder um is included, '"-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um"'.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: By adding #include <windows.h> to my header file I was able to compile without getting the original 'HANDLE'  error.  The next layer of this onion, I'm getting the following fatal link error:  d:\cython\test.cp36-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120.  Now I'm guessing that my setup.py is not including the .lib files needed, is 'library_dir' not the correct way to include .lib?  Thanks.

Comment: @sallwine  LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pxd_PIXCIclose says it can not find pxd_PIXCIclose. While this is might be simple, as adding new /LIBPATH to point to the location of the library where this name is, it also might be complicated for the few reasons. Please have a look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx
If you know the library name, you can also try to add in your code 
#pragma comment(lib, "library name you need.lib") directive.

Answer (score 0):

By adding #include windows.h to my header and then changing my original setup.py to the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize


ext_modules = Extension(
          name = "test",
          sources=["test.pyx"],

          include_dirs=["D:\epix\lib", "D:\epix\inc"],
          library_dirs=["D:\epix\inc"],
          libraries=["XCLIBW64", "PXIPLW64"]

          )

setup(
name = "test.pyx",
ext_modules = cythonize([ext_modules])
```

I was able to successfully cythonize one of the functions in my c project.  Thank you to all who gave me suggestions that pointed me in the right direction.